# Exception handling in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on ASP.NET application with VB.NET as backend. I am facing a problem with an unhandled exception on production. Currently i am using block level exception handing:

2) page_error - page level handling

3) application_error - application level

Still there is some point where errors are skipping and yellow screen is coming at production. I found this article http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/catching-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net/.

I implemented the `UnhandledExceptionModule`, but I am unable to test this as all my exception are caught earlier in code and I am unable to implement `[System.Security.SecurityCritical]` due to version difference, since I am using framework 2.0 only.

Please suggest how to overcome this issues or some other way to handle them.

Comment: What the 'yellow' error is? It is possible that the ASP.NET engine fails even before your application got hit!

Comment: yellow error means client is having yellow screen at there with unhandled exceptions - application working fine but some unhandled exceptions are skipping page level and application level error handling blocks and causing this issue

Comment: I know what 'yellow' error is! I ask you about your specific 'yellow' error!

Comment: it is error regarding GetSession() - unhandled exception come when application pool recycle and session are unable to get. (it is what i assume)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set the application pool recycling to happen at a set time, say 3 a.m. if no-one is likely to be using the web site at that time. [Configure an Application Pool to Recycle at a Scheduled Time (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754494%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (you didn't mention which version of IIS you're using).
2. If you use out-of-process session state, the session state is not affected by the recycling. [Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I suggest using State Server Mode as it is simple to set up.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle errors a bit more gracefully in ASP.NET is to use a combination of CustomError page(s) so the end user doesn't see the infamous "Yellow Screen of Death" along with some technique for logging the error details so that the specific issue can be resolved later.

**Presenting Users a Custom Error Page**

In my experience the best way to handle this in ASP.NET is to use the customErrors node in web.config like so:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Default.aspx">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/Default/Unauthorized.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Default/PageNotFound.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Default/PageNotFound.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="408" redirect="~/Error/Default/RequestTimeout.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="505" redirect="~/Error/Default/NotSupported.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

This node lives in /configuration/system.web/customErrors.  Here's a [link with more information written by ASP.NET guru Scott Mitchell](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs).  The "defaultRedirect" attribute on the customError node tells ASP.NET which page to display if an unhandled exception is thrown.  Here is an example of a custom error page which seemed to work well with users on our local intranet and although it is written for MVC it should be easy enough to translate it to WebForms:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Master/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" 
             ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" 
             runat="server">
         Unknown Error - Organization or Website Name
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div id="error">
    <h3 id="status">Something Unexpected Happened</h3>
    <p id="details" style="margin-top: 15px">
        Your request could not be fully processed most likely because of a computer programming 
        or data corruption problem.  Errors like these are logged with the date, time, a 
        detailed error message (sometimes called a stack trace), the errant URL, and normally 
        the user making the request along with some additional information.  
        <br />
        <br />
        The web team tries to check and troubleshoot these logs daily depending on our 
        general work load.  If you're having a problem that can be repeated, please send 
        me a message and include the current time (<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>) along 
        with a brief description of what you were trying to do.  Feedback of this nature is
        appreciated and absolutely essential.
    </p>
    <p>
        --
        <br />
        Organization Web Team or Appropriate Help Desk<br />
        Phone: (555) 555-5555<br />
        Email: <a href="mailto:web.team@your.organization.org?subject=Application%20Error">web.team@your.organization.org</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Logging Unhandled Exceptions**

One of my favorite ways to log unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET is by using the "Health Monitoring System".  Here, again, is [another article by Scott Mitchell which describes ASP.NET's Health Monitoring System](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-asp-net-health-monitoring-vb).  Health Monitoring was introduced in the 2.0 framework so it should be useful for your application.  Briefly said Health Monitoring can be used to log unhandled exceptions to a database, the event-viewer, and can email them as well all out of the box.  It can also be extended with a bit of work and can be used to log handled exceptions as well.  As the article points out Health Monitoring is configured via web.config at node /configuration/system.web/healthMonitoring.